# Is there any way to back up the default fonts in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, fonts, windows-8-fonts

I want to be able to back up my default fonts from my ***Windows 8 Pro*** install. I'm going to be doing some stuff with my fonts, and I want to be able to get back all those is something happens to them. Typing in *"C:\Windows\Fonts"* just opens up the Font *Control Panel* page. They don't want to copy from there it seems. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Also keep an eye on [Restore Default Font Files in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/525298/restore-default-font-files-in-windows-8). :)

Comment: [according to this question](http://superuser.com/questions/905129/how-to-backup-the-fonts-in-windows-8-to-transfer-to-a-fresh-windows-reinstallati) in Windows 8 they are no longer stored in the windows fonts folder??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this command line from an elevated command prompt:

`copy foo:\windows\fonts\*.* bar`

(foo stands for your windows installation drive letter; bar stands for destination path.)

It should do the job.