# How to backup the fonts in Windows 8 to transfer to a fresh windows reinstallation?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, fonts, windows-8-fonts

In previous versions of windows they were easily found in c:\windows\fonts folder.

Now the font files are distributed across multiple folders in c:\windows\winsxs

I understand that this was a measure regarding license issues, but all the fonts I used in my previous Windows installation are properly licensed. I just want to make a backup to all of them at once for a new Windows installation, without the need to find each one again and install them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open *Fonts* view under *Control Panel* and copy all fonts from there to a folder of your choosing.

Comment: that was incredible easy, makes me look bad to myself